# how to use IsKindOf() function to check two objects?

Tags: mfc, visual-c++

I know that ISKINDOF() function is used to compare two class objects that is declared **DECLARE_DYNAMIC**.

But the problem is how to compare the object pointers that is not declared **DECLARE_DYNAMIC**.

```
    CSample *sample1, *sample2;
    sample1.ISKINDOF(sample2);
```

definetely the above sample will show error .

Is there any function to check the above constraints?

Comment: I think the real problem is one level deeper, and you are searching for a solution for the wrong question. Why do you need to check these pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, this solution does require deriving from CObject and using `DECLARE_DYNAMIC` and `IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC`. Is there some reason you can't use them?

Get the Runtime Class of the object that should be the same as or superclass of the other object. Assuming you think sample2 is the same class or a superclass of sample1:

```
CRuntimeClass* pClass = sample2->GetRunTimeClass();
BOOL sample1IsKindOfSample2 = sample1->IsKindOf(pClass);
```

Comment: But you still need to derive from `CObject` to do this.

Comment: My mistake, I missed that key element.

Answer (score 0):

If your VC++ code is compiled /GR (which is the default in recent compilers/IDEs) then you can use dynamic_cast to explore the runtime type of objects.

However, as DWO hints in his comment, designs that use ISKINDOF et al should often be replaced with other designs (such as a virtual function).

Martyn